# Javascript seems to be skipping a line when implementing (if count === 1)

Tags: javascript

I am doing an exercise in a textbook which does not provide an answer or an example for its assignment. It is the age-old 99 Bottles of Beer on the wall javascript program. After searching online, I only found examples that are coded very differently than how the book has been teaching me so far. My issue is that when I get to the bottom (1 bottle) the first line always says "1 bottles" even though the rest adjust to "1 bottle". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm eager to learn! Thanks everyone! I've included a jsfiddle.

```
var word = "bottles";
var count = 99;
while (count > 0) {
    console.log(count + " " + word + " of beer on the wall ");
    console.log(count + " " + word + " of beer,");
    console.log("Take one down, pass it around,");
    count = count - 1;
    if (count > 0) {
        console.log(count + " " + word + " of beer on the wall."); 
    if (count === 1)
        word = "bottle";
    } else {
            console.log("No more bottles of beer on the wall.");
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mmaffia92/3jp0fjya/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code logs "1 bottles of beer on the wall." is because you are changing the value of `word` *after* you log that expression. To fix this issue while making the least amount of changes to your code, you would need only to reverse the order of the conditional assignment of `word` and the `console.log`:

```
if (count > 0) {
    if (count === 1) {
        word = "bottle";
    }
    // Note that the log will occur after the word = "bottle" assigment.
    console.log(count + " " + word + " of beer on the wall.");
} else {
    console.log("No more bottles of beer on the wall.");
}
```

Additionally, I want to note that I have added curly braces around the `word = "bottle";` block. These are not necessary, but, I feel, make for much more readable code. At a glance, your `else` block looks like it corresponds to `if (count === 1)`, but it actually corresponds to `if (count > 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move a couple of lines around and, in particular, move the line re no more bottles *outside* of the loop otherwise it will never run (count will always be greater than 0 in the loop).

```
var count = 99;
var word;

while (count > 0) {
  var word = count === 1 ? "bottle" : 'bottles';
  console.log(count + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
  console.log(count + " " + word + " of beer,");
  console.log("Take one down, pass it around,");
  count = count - 1;
  if (count > 0) {
    word = count === 1 ? "bottle" : 'bottles';
    console.log(count + " " + word + " of beer on the wall.");
    console.log('');
  }
}


console.log("No more bottles of beer on the wall.");
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3jp0fjya/4/)

If you wanted to you could replace that `if` statement with a ternary expression to make it more concise:

```
var word = count === 1 ? 'bottle' : 'bottles';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually that seems to modify the code itself and change it to only repeat '# bottles of beer on the wall' one time instead of twice.

Comment: Ah, thank you! For some reason the Demo isn't correct but I changed my code to what you suggested and it works perfectly. It does introduce a few concepts that the textbook didn't go over yet, though, so I'm wondering if there are possibly other ways of solving the issue. Either way, thanks a lot for your time!